# Is this VBA function going to work in any computer?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this VBA function to retrieve data from a website. The function is working fine for me. But I am not sure it will work for the client, who may have internet access restrictions imposed by their company. How can I be sure it will work on every computer? Should I add a proxy? How would I do it?

```
'func1 and func2 are strings used to compose the URL

Function cmd(func1 As String, func2 As String)
   Dim objHTTP
   Dim aux
   Dim url As String

   'Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
   Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
   url = "https://www.comdinheiro.com.br/Clientes/ServerToExcel/S2E_TESTANDO001.php?func1=" & func1 & "&func2=" & func2
   objHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
   objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
     'objHTTP.SetProxy 2, "proxyserver:8080", ""
   objHTTP.SetProxy HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY, "ProxyServerName"
   objHTTP.Send ("")
   aux = objHTTP.responseText

   cmd = Trim(aux)

End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you are probably going to need to test it in different environments.

Comment: Are you just trying to make sure the code runs without an error dialog even if there is no internet connection?  Try using error catching with either `On Error Resume Next` or `On Error Goto Label` to trap the error and display a "No Internet Connection" Msgbox

Comment: There is _no_ way to guarantee that a certain code will work the same on all systems. Other obstacles could be office versions and os versions. You will simply have to test it and possibly set up error catching to account for issues like can't reach the website.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding proxy. If your code should be launched on PC with internet access via proxy, where user connection to internet in IE starts from the dialog like
[image: authorization dialog]
or
[image]
then you may add user and password in fourth and fifth parameters of `objHTTP.Open` described in [open method article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763809.aspx):

```
objHTTP.Open "GET", url, False, user, password
```

Note, you must not store any passwords in your code, to submit credentials you have to prompt user to enter it once at the start of your code.

Also analyzing VBA `Err.Number` for errors like -2146697211 (800C0005) "The system cannot locate the resource specified.", -2147024891 (80070005) "Access is denied.", etc, and `objHTTP.Status` for one from the [status property article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767625.aspx) will help you to find out what is the reason of fault, and handle it, if any:

```
' ... previous code implementing .open method
On Error Resume Next
objHTTP.Send ("")
EN = Err.Number
On Error Goto 0
' check if EN is not equal 0 (-2146697211, -2147024891, ..)
ST = objHTTP.Status
' check if ST is not equal 200
```

First of all you should figure out in your code if internet access is via proxy and need authentication or not. To allow your code work properly on both you may create two functions that return created HttpRequest object: first one for non-proxy internet access, second - for proxy authorization.

Registry keys can also be helpful:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer

Generally, as @Degustaf wrote you have to test your code on different PCs to be sure your algorithm for proxy check and authorization works properly.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try and see what happens.